# TextInput component in React Native accepts any character, when pasting, not depends on keyboardType

Tags: react-native

TextInput component should not accept other characters than numeric.

The real problem is that when you paste inside TextInput: `555 555 555`, instead of `555555555`, I get `555 555 5`.

Other than that, I can paste whatever I want  `^*D+-/6`.

I tried regex on

```
function handler(e) {
  const tmp =  e.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');       
  setValue(tmp)
}
```

Is there any good way I can catch paste event or something?

Code is simple:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
    
  function handler(e) {
    setValue(e);
  }
    
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={handler}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        maxLength={9}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can catch a paste event.
One way to solve your particular issue is to use regex **and** enforce maxLength from your onChangeText Handler.

---

Example

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  function handler(text) {
    if (text.length >= value.length + 2){
      // Maybe this can be captured as a paste event?
      // Haven't tested it, but it's an idea.
      // Since key-ins cannot increase the length of the value by 
      // more than 1 at a time, if text length increase by 2 or more,
      // then I think it's safe to assume it's a paste event.
    }

    const maxLength = 9
    let cleanNumber = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
    if (cleanNumber.length > maxLength) {
      cleanNumber = cleanNumber.substr(0, maxLength)
    }
    setValue(cleanNumber);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={handler}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        // maxLength={9} <-- Don't use maxLength prop here.
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```